# javascript - setTimeout after button click

Tags: javascript

How can I setup `setTimeout`'function after a button got clicked ?

I'd like the spinner icon to disappear after 5 seconds.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#btnreg').click(function()
        {
            $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin">');

        });
    });
```

and this the HTML of my button:

```
<button type="submit" name="register" id="btnreg" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Start</button>
```

Thanks, regards!

Comment: Have you tried using the setTimeout function in there?

Comment: How your requirements are different from any other where one need to introduce a delay via `setTimeout`? What have you tried and what was the problem you ran into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#btnreg').click(function(){ 
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin"></i>'); 
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("fa-spin");
}, 5000);
    });
```

I'm guessing `fa-spin` is your class to show icon. So, your problem will be solved if you remove this class after 5s and icon will be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your functionality by bellow code

```
$(function()
{
    $('#btnreg').click(function()
    {
        $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-cog fa-spin"></i> start');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#btnreg').html('start');
        }, 5000);
    })
})
```